# Encoding problems in Wordpress "Title" to custom JSON

Tags: json, wordpress, encoding, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

First question here.

I'm trying to make a custom API in Wordpress with register_rest_route() and some **CPT** (with CPT-UI Plugin). But some strange things are happening..

In the title of the post (WP Editor), if I put a "-" (hyphen) it shows `&#8212;` (Em-dash) in the JSON.
And if I inspect the source code of the WP post it shows `&#8211;` (En-dash).

Example..

Title in WP Editor: "Card nº 1 - PT" [hiphen]
Response in JSON: `Card nº 1 &#8212; PT` [it assumes a coded m-dash not an hyphen]

But if I change it to..

Title in WP Editor: "Card nº 1 _ PT" [underscore]
Response in JSON: "Card nº 1 _ PT" [Ok]

It seems to be an encoding problem with En-dash.

I've changed another question related to this from here to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71517487/removing-html-comments-from-wordpress-blocks-in-json)

Thanks for listening!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you creating these posts in the Editor or are you programatically inserting them with a hyphen in title? If you create the post via the Editor, does your raw JSON contain `&#8211;`  in place of the hyphen?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @S.Walsh
I've just realized I didn't "coded" some characters in the post, it was hard to understand. I've corrected that and also added some more info to clarify.
Thanks!

Comment: Meanwhile I've tested render it and, if having an hyphen, an En or Em-dash is not relevan't, it worked fine with innerHTML.
Thanks